# Вопрос по WP - Woocommerce: где можно изменить кол-во дней для товаров-новинок?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

С помощью шорткода [recent_products] можно вывести последние товары (новинки). А где можно задать количество дней, на протяжении которого товар считается новинкой (по умолчанию даже не знаю сколько, но мне нужно 5)? Искал в админке, файле функций Woocommerce, но безуспешно.

UPD. Скорее всего данный шорткод выводит последние добавленные товары. Тогда вопрос - можно ли задать этим товарам лимит времени, если прошло 5 дней, то они переставали быть recent_products?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302186/woocommerce-only-show-products-between-start-and-end-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужный для изучения код находится в файлах

`wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\shortcodes\class-wc-shortcode-products.php` и

`wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php`.

Вам нужно отфильтровать аргументы WP_Query для фильтра recent_posts. Добавьте следующий фильтр в `functions.php` вашей темы:

```
/**
 * Filter woocommerce_shortcode_products_query.
 *
 * @param array  $query_args Query arguments.
 * @param array  $attributes Attributes.
 * @param string $type       Shortcode type.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function my_woocommerce_shortcode_products_query( $query_args, $attributes, $type ) {
    if ( 'recent_products' !== $type ) {
        return $query_args;
    }

    $query_args['date_query'] = [
        [
            'after'  => '-5 days',
            'column' => 'post_date',
        ],
    ];

    return $query_args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'my_woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 10, 3 );
```